# Help on making Google Sheets script quicker and more efficient

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have the following script, and I would like to know if there is anyway to make it more efficient? It works great, but takes a little time to do what it needs to do. Mainly is there a way to condense the clearContent() into one and any other ways to make it more efficient will be appreciated.

```
function onEdit(){
  var tabLists = "Master";
  var tabValidation = "Planning";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(tabLists);
  
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 3 && activeCell.getRow() > 4 && ss.getSheetName() == tabValidation){
    
    activeCell.offset(0,1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
    activeCell.offset(0,4).clearContent();
    activeCell.offset(0,5).clearContent();
    activeCell.offset(0,6).clearContent();
    activeCell.offset(0,9).clearContent();
    activeCell.offset(0,12).clearContent();
    activeCell.offset(0,16).clearContent();
    activeCell.offset(0,21).clearContent();
    
    var makes = datass.getRange(3, 1, 1, datass.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    
    var makeIndex = makes[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;
    
    if(makeIndex != 0){
    
        var validationRange = datass.getRange(4, makeIndex, datass.getLastRow());
        var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
        activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
  
     }  
      
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please read [Best Practices : Batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations). If you need further help, please show what you have tried to make your script more efficient and add a brief description of your [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search) efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: you might want to use the following syntax:

activeCell.Range("a2:a10").clearContent()

if they are contiguous

Comment: Exact copy of [Help on making Google Sheets script quicker and more efficient](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/159067846) that already has an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is Recommended Answer taken from Google Support:  [Help on making Google Sheets script quicker and more efficient (clearContent())](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/159067846). Answer by Hyde.

---

I do not know what your code is really supposed to do, because you have not described your requirements, and there is no sample spreadsheet that would allow testing. Nevertheless, you may want to try something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Master');
  const validationSheet = 'Planning';
 
  let sheet;
  if (e.range.columnStart !== 3
    || e.range.rowStart <= 4
    || (sheet = e.range.getSheet()).getSheetName() !== validationSheet) {
    return;
  }
  const columnNumbers = [1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 12, 16, 21]
    .map(offset => e.range.columnStart + offset);
  const rangesA1 = columnNumbersToColumnLabels_(columnNumbers)
    .map(columnLetter => columnLetter + e.range.rowStart);
  sheet.getRangeList(rangesA1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
 
  const makes = dataSheet.getRange(3, 1, 1, dataSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const makeIndex = makes[0].indexOf(e.value) + 1;
  if (makeIndex !== 0) {
    const validationRange = dataSheet.getRange(4, makeIndex, dataSheet.getLastRow());
    const validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
    e.range.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
  }
}
 

/**
* Converts column numbers such as 1, 26, 27 and 18278 into column labels like "A", "Z", "AA" and "ZZZ".
*
* Returns a text string or an array of text strings that matches the dimensions of numbers.
* Supports single values and arrays like [1, 26, 27] or [[1, 2], [13, 14], [27, 28]].
* Returns null for '', null and undefined.
* Returns NaN for non-numbers and numbers less than 1.
*
* @param {Number[][]} numbers A column number or or an array of column numbers to convert to column labels.
* @return {String[][]} Column labels like "A", "Z", "AA" and "ZZZ", or NaN if numbers is not a positive number.
*/
function columnNumbersToColumnLabels_(numbers) {
  // version 1.7, written by --Hyde 3 November 2019
  if (Array.isArray(numbers)) {
    return numbers.map(columnNumbersToColumnLabels_);
  }
  if (numbers === '' || (numbers == null)) {
    return null;
  }
  if (typeof numbers !== 'number' || numbers < 1) {
    return NaN;
  }
  var alphabetStart = 'A'.charCodeAt(0);
  var alphabetSize = 'Z'.charCodeAt(0) - alphabetStart + 1;
  var colLabel = '';
  while (numbers > 0) {
    var colNumber = (numbers - 1) % alphabetSize;
    var asciiCode = colNumber + alphabetStart;
    colLabel = String.fromCharCode(asciiCode) + colLabel;
    numbers = (numbers - colNumber - 1) / alphabetSize;
  }
  return colLabel;
}
```

Comment: The idea of marking an answer a community wiki is to allow users with rep >= 100 to edit it without passing through the edit proposal queue. Is that what you are looking for making this answer a community wiki?

Comment: No. Looks like I made (yet another) mistake, Rubén. As noted by doubleunary, there is an exact duplicate question (with an answer) on Google support. Rather than leave  _this_ question without an answer, I copied the answer from Google support, I didn’t want to get any reputation points so I did it as Community Wiki.

Comment: I will not call this a mistake since I have seen many users that have did  the same when for any reason they don't want to gain reputation but many of them apparently were not aware of the "side-effects". Now you know a bit more about how [se] works :)